# Using BeautifulSoup to extract specific text within duplicate tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a Digital Humanities project trying to isolate just the descriptions of images from a series of digitized engravings. (I am also fairly new to coding and programming in general as I am just a humble philosopher stepping into the waters of DH) So far I have been able to isolate the source code using Python and a urllib script which looks like this:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse


url = "http://pitts.emory.edu/dia/image_details.cfm?ID=17250"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

However, my issue arises in the source code itself. The description is situated with other pieces of information which are all broken up by P and b tags:

```html
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">                                                
    <P>
      <b>Book Title:</b>
      <A HREF="book_detail.cfm?ID=2449">The Holy Bible containing the Old and New Testaments, according to the authorised version. With illustrations by Gustave Doré</a>
    </p>              
    <P>
        <b>Author:</b> Doré, Gustave, 1832-1883
    </p>
    
    <P>
        <b>Image Title:</b> Baptism of Jesus
    </p>
    <P>
      <b>Scripture Reference:</b><ul><li>John 1 (<a href='search.cfm?biblicalbook=John&biblicalbookchapter=1'>further images</a> / <a rel='shadowbox;height=500;width=600' href='http://www.commonenglishbible.com/explore/passage-lookup/?query=John+1'>scripture text</a>)</li></ul>
    </p>
    <P>
        <b>Description:</b> John the Baptist baptizes Jesus in the Jordan River; the Holy Spirit appears overhead in the form of a dove. The artist, Gustave Doré (1832-1883), has placed his signature at the lower left of the woodcut, and the engraver’s signature, A. Ligny, is located at the lower right.
    </P>
    <P>
        <A HREF="book_list.cfm?ID=2449">Click here
        </a> for additional images available from this book.
    </P>
    <p>For information on licensing this image, please send an email, including a link to the image, to 
        <a href="mailto:dia@emory.edu?subject=Licensing%20Image%20From%20DIA - 17250">dia@emory.edu</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I use BeautifulSoup to isolate just the text of the description in from out of these tags? Everything I have thus far found on StackOverFlow suggests it may be doable; however I have yet to find something trying to do this specifically.

Again, out of the source code, I want to extract just the description "John the Baptist baptizes Jesus...". How could I go about doing this?

Thanks! And sorry again for my lack of robust knowledge just yet.

Answer (score 3):

In this example, we can use CSS selectors. Assuming you are using BeautifulSoup 4.7+, CSS selector support is provided by the [soupsieve](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/) library. We are first going to use the `:has()` CSS level 4 selector to find `<p>` tags who have a direct child `<b>` tag, and then use the soupsieve's non-standard `:contains` selector to ensure the `<b>` tag contains `Description:`. Then we simply print the content of all elements that match this criteria stripping out leading and trailing whitespace and stripping out `Description:`.  Keep in mind there are multiple ways to do this, this is just the method I've chosen to illustrate:

```py
import bs4

markup = """
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<P>
    <b>Book Title:</b>
    <A HREF="book_detail.cfm?ID=2449">The Holy Bible containing the Old and New Testaments, according to the authorised version. With illustrations by Gustave Doré</a>
</p>


    <P>
        <b>Author:</b> Doré, Gustave, 1832-1883
    </p>

    <P>
        <b>Image Title:</b> Baptism of Jesus
    </p>

    <P>
        <b>Scripture Reference:</b><ul><li>John 1 (<a href='search.cfm?biblicalbook=John&biblicalbookchapter=1'>further images</a> / <a rel='shadowbox;height=500;width=600' href='http://www.commonenglishbible.com/explore/passage-lookup/?query=John+1'>scripture text</a>)</li></ul>
    </p>

        <P>
            <b>Description:</b> John the Baptist baptizes Jesus in the Jordan River; the Holy Spirit appears overhead in the form of a dove. The artist, Gustave Doré (1832-1883), has placed his signature at the lower left of the woodcut, and the engraver’s signature, A. Ligny, is located at the lower right.
        </P>


    <P>
        <A HREF="book_list.cfm?ID=2449">Click here
        </a> for additional images available from this book.
    </P>

    <p>For information on licensing this image, please send an email, including a link to the image, to 
        <a href="mailto:dia@emory.edu?subject=Licensing%20Image%20From%20DIA - 17250">dia@emory.edu</a>
    </p>


</div>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")

for el in soup.select('p:has(> b:contains("Description:"))'):
    print(el.get_text().strip('').replace('Description: ', ''))
```

Output:

```
John the Baptist baptizes Jesus in the Jordan River; the Holy Spirit appears overhead in the form of a dove. The artist, Gustave Doré (1832-1883), has placed his signature at the lower left of the woodcut, and the engraver’s signature, A. Ligny, is located at the lower right.
```

Comment: Finally bs4 is improving what you can do with css. + for this

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually the author of external library that now handles the CSS for bs4.  Just trying to get the word out as there is some cool stuff you can do with selectors.

Comment: I’m so pleased! Congrats. First I had heard about it.

Comment: Yes! This worked. Thank you so much. Now I just have to figure out how to make this run for every image in the archive haha

Comment: If they all follow the same format, this should work for all of them. That is why there is a for loop to loop through the what `select` returns. You just have to run the entirety of the HTML content through BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3):

I could achieve something almost like you wanted using the below code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://pitts.emory.edu/dia/image_details.cfm?ID=17250"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
parent = soup.find("b", text="Description:").parent
parent.find("b", text="Description:").decompose()
print(parent.text)
```

I've added BeautifulSoup and removed the Description.

Answer (score 0):

I used < p > tags as index and than choosed the [4] index. I am just a newbie, but it worked.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://pitts.emory.edu/dia/image_details.cfm?ID=17250")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
page = soup.find_all('p')[4].getText()

print(page)
```